# How to delete an object from an array when stored in Firestore

Tags: .net, google-cloud-firestore, f#

I would like to delete the object with id number 2 in this Firestore object. Is that possible?

```
{
    "provider": "foo",
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with this although it may be inefficient:

```
let! existingDoc = collection
                            .Document("foo")
                            .GetSnapshotAsync()

let datalist = existingDoc.GetValue<List<DataRecord>>("data")

let filteredList = datalist.Where(fun x -> x.id <> "2").ToList()

collection
         .Document("foo")
         .UpdateAsync("data", filteredList)
```